# C# Add List<string> to List<List<string>> array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm able to add `List<string>` in `List<List<string>>` array in this way:

```
        List<string> first = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
        List<string> second = new List<string> { "four", "five", "six" };

        List<List<string>> list_array = new List<List<string>> { first, second };
```

Now I need to create several lists populated with database records and then to add this lists to `List<List<string>>` array:

```
    List<List<string>> array_list;

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string one = dr["Row1"].ToString();
                string two = dr["Row2"].ToString();

                List<string> temp_list = new List<string> { one, two };

                //Here I need to add temp_list to array_list
            }
```

Comment: What is your question here? Are you not able to add temp to array ? What have you tried? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @ryadavilli hes asking how to add the temp_list to the array_list, hes shows he has tried creating the lists and is unsure how to continue, he isnt getting any errors because he hasnt yet added it. his previous attempts to add arent shown because they either give compilation errors or dont work and he has discovered that. 

any more questions? :P

Comment: @RhysW Good that you have understood his intent. But it will not be painfully obvious to everyone. Hence, I asked these questions. On SO, we expect that there are questions and not deduce that something is missing because there is no code in the sample. Also, we expect poster to mention what they have tried and where they are stuck.

Comment: @ryadavilli , you can see my question in the code in comment line: //Here I need to add temp_list to array_list. 
Also there is explanation what I'm trying to do: Now I need to create several lists populated with database records and then to add this lists to List<List<string>> array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an empty array_list:

```
List<List<string>> array_list = new List<List<string>>();
```

Then use `Add` method to add items:

```
array_list.Add(temp_list);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your variable declaration to initialize an empty List:

```
List<List<string>> array_list = new List<List<string>>();
```

Then, just call .Add();

```
List<string> temp_list = new List<string> { one, two };

//Here I need to add temp_list to array_list
array_list.Add(temp_list);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
array_list.Add(temp_list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless i'm reading this wrong, you should just be able to do:

```
array_list.add(temp_list);
```

Comment: only if his first instantiation of array_list is set to be a new List<List<String>> to begin with

Answer (score 2):

```
List<List<string>> array_list = new List<List<string>>();

while (dr.Read())
{
   string one = dr["Row1"].ToString();
   string two = dr["Row2"].ToString();
   List<string> temp_list = new List<string> { one, two };
   array_list.add(temp_list)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<List<string>> array_list = new List<List<string>>();
while (dr.Read())
        {
            string one = dr["Row1"].ToString();
            string two = dr["Row2"].ToString();

            List<string> temp_list = new List<string> { one, two };

            array_list.Add(temp_list);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add directly;

```
array_list.Add(temp_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to alweys remeber to make new temp_list, don't use temp_list.clear(), like I did in my project =_=.

> Blockquote

```
 List<List<string>> array_list = new List<List<string>>();
    while (dr.Read())
            {
                string one = dr["Row1"].ToString();
                string two = dr["Row2"].ToString();

                List<string> temp_list = new List<string> { one, two };

                array_list.Add(temp_list);
            }
```

> Blockquote